What does it mean "barcheinu be-ohr panecha" according to sod?
BH
Hi.
In Shmona Esre in Sim Shalom we say "barcheinu avinu kulanu ke-echad be-ohr panecha".
What does "be-ohr panecha" mean according to sod?
Does face mean chochma also?

In context, the term פניך is referring to G-d’s name מלץ or צלם, or when including the letters and kollel, צלמו, which is the name intended at the beginning of the Amidah prayer with the expression, אל עליון. That צלמו is related to the first name that was revealed to Moshe Rabbeinu when he was told to redeem the children of Israel from Egypt. באור meaning ב׳ פעמים אור which is ואהבת.
